# How do i manage my Highcharts drilldown with multiple Json URL?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Im trying to create a column highcharts with 4 drilldown levels with also 4 Json URL.

so actually upon loading my chart it will show the first json URL Data with the data of:

```
[
    {
        "New_Students": "84",
        "NSYEAR": "2014",
        "NSterm": null,
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "1892",
        "NSYEAR": "2015",
        "NSterm": null,
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "2107",
        "NSYEAR": "2016",
        "NSterm": null,
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "1119",
        "NSYEAR": "2017",
        "NSterm": null,
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "2090",
        "NSYEAR": "2018",
        "NSterm": null,
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    }
]
```

so upon clicking the Column with the specific year example Year 2014 with the value of 84 New_Students, it must show a drilldown for my 2nd Json URL with the parameter of "2014" which is the year that the user clicked

```
[
    {
        "New_Students": "618",
        "NSYEAR": null,
        "NSterm": "1401",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "149",
        "NSYEAR": null,
        "NSterm": "1402",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "1",
        "NSYEAR": null,
        "NSterm": "1403",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    }
]
```

it will show here the school term under "2014" Year which is the "1401" "1402" "1403" NSTerm.

here is my code for Javascript. but upon clicking the column nothing happens the drilldown is not working :(

```
<script>
     var strCampus = "<%=MyProperty%>";
    var OnClickYearVal;
    var Year = [];

    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:37590/get_NSData/' + strCampus , function (jsonData) { 
            const data = jsonData
            console.log(data);

let categories = [],
  series = [],
  i,
  j;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    categories[i] = data[i].NSYEAR
        //+ '-' + [parseFloat(data[i].NSYEAR) + 1];
  Year = [data[i].NSYEAR]
  series.push({
      name: [+data[i].NSYEAR] + ' School Year',
      //data: [+data[i].New_Students],
      data: [{

          y: +data[i].New_Students,
          drilldown: true
      }]
  });

  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    series[i].data.unshift(null);
  }
}

Highcharts.chart('YearNS', {
       chart: {
         width: 1150,
         height: 450,
         type: 'column',
          events: {
              drilldown: function (e) {
                  if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                      var chart = this;

                          $.get('http://localhost:37590/get_NSDataTerm/' + e.point.categories + '/' + 2018, function (jsonData) {

                              this.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point,jsonData);
                          });

                  }
              }

       }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Number of New Students for ' + Year + 'SY'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view the breakdown by Term. Click again to view by Program. Updated as of Yesterday 11:59PM'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: categories.length - 1,
    crosshair: false,
        categories: categories

             },
     legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            verticalAlign: 'top',

            floating: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
        },
      plotOptions: {
          series: {

            borderWidth: 2,
           pointWidth: 100,
            dataLabels: {
                inside: true,
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:,.0f}',
                style: {
                    textShadow: false,
                    textOutline: false,
                    color: 'black'
                },
            }
          },

           column: {
               events: {

               }
              },
    },
    series: series,
      drilldown: {
        series: []
    }
        });
        });
        });
</script>
```

this is my problem for almost 2 weeks and im just a beginner in highcharts and json URL.

Comment: You need to pass the corresponding series of data in your `drilldown` object. See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/. Currently your `drilldown` contains a single empty `series` key.

Comment: hi vladimir, im new using highcharts and the thing that makes me confuse is on how will i code the new URL json upon drilldown and pass that data on that drilldown depends on what column that the user clicked